# How do I read and save all cloudant documents in a list

Tags: node.js, nosql, cloudant

So I'm trying to pull all the data out of cloudant database using Node.js and I'm having some issues figuring out how to get all my documents. Basically, I have a whole react webpage built, but I'm new to Node.js and cloudant. Using just the node run command I can connect to my database pull/log the database information, but I'm having trouble getting to the documents and then putting all their data in a list, so i can create a table view of the data. Any suggestions would be amazing and I obviously removed my credentials for security purposes.

```
var cloudant = new Cloudant({ url: 'xxxx', plugins: { iamauth: { iamApiKey: 'xxxx' } } });

cloudant.db.list(function(err, body) {
    body.forEach(function(db) {
     console.log(db);

     });

});`


var readDocument = function(callback) {
    console.log("Reading document 'slay-data'");
    cloudant.db.get('slay-data', function(err, data) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
      console.log('Data:', data);
      // keep a copy of the doc so you know its revision token
      doc = [data];


      callback(err, data);
      //console.log(doc);
    });
    cloudant.db.list(function (err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
      });
};
var docu = readDocument();
console.log(docu)
```

Comment: Can you please describe the expected output and what you are experiencing instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the data out of a Cloudant database you can do this (I've switched to async/await Node, as it's easier to read:

```js
const cloudant = new Cloudant({ url: 'xxxx', plugins: { iamauth: { iamApiKey: 'xxxx' } } });
const db = cloudant.db.use('mydb')

const readAllData = async function () {
  // extract all the data, including the document bodies
  const response = await db.list({ include_docs: true })
  // response.rows is an array with a 'doc' attribute for each document
  const docs = response.rows.map((r) => { return r.doc })
  return docs
}

readAllData()
```